# Prevent automatic type conversion in ctypes callback functions

Tags: python, callback, python-3.x, type-conversion, ctypes

When wrapping Python functions with a [`CFUNCTYPE`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/ctypes.html#callback-functions) type, I've found that the non-pointer types are automatically converted as though their [`value`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/ctypes.html#ctypes._SimpleCData.value) attribute was called.

How can I suppress this automatic conversion?

```
from ctypes import *

funcspec = CFUNCTYPE(c_int, c_int, POINTER(c_int))

@funcspec
def callback(the_int, the_int_p):
    print(vars())
    return 3

print(callback(c_int(1), byref(c_int(2))))
```

Which produces (`python3`[`cfunctype_type_conversion.py`](http://code.google.com/p/anacrolix/source/browse/public/stackoverflow/cfunctype_type_conversion.py)):

```
{'the_int': 1, 'the_int_p': <__main__.LP_c_int object at 0x2671830>}
3
```

I'd like:

```
{'the_int': c_int(1), 'the_int_p': <__main__.LP_c_int object at 0x2671830>}
c_int(3)
```

Comment: Isn't doing this exactly the purpose of CFUNCTYPE? The purpose of ctypes is to interface with C-API's and convert back and forth from C types and Python types. You aren't supposed to keep the c_int's around and do things with them directly. You can't, for example, add a c_int to another c_int.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit of a hack, but it might work for you. Hopefully someone else will chime in with a cleaner way..

```
from ctypes import *

class c_int_hack(c_int):
    def from_param(self, *args):
        return self

funcspec = CFUNCTYPE(c_int, c_int_hack, POINTER(c_int))

@funcspec
def callback(the_int, the_int_p):
    print(vars())
    print(the_int.value)
    return 3

print(callback(c_int(1), byref(c_int(2))))
```

..and the output is:

```
{'the_int': <c_int_hack object at 0xb7478b6c>, 'the_int_p': <__main__.LP_c_long object at 0xb747892c>}
1
3
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking at the ctypes code recently, thought I might be able to figure this one out.  The c code that does this is in callproc.c (here's the [source for 2.7.2](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8527427914a2/Modules/_ctypes/callproc.c)).

A relevant comment from the source:

> *5*. If 'converters' are present (converters is a sequence of argtypes'
>   from_param methods), for each item in
>   'callargs' converter is called and the
>   result passed to ConvParam.  If
>   'converters' are not present, each
>   argument is directly passed to
>   ConvParm.

Which is pretty much what Luke said, so what he gave is probably not a hack.